# How do I determine the right boundarys for this Integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $ G := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | -y<x<y^2, 0<y<1 \} $
and $ B:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0 \leq y, x^2+ \frac{y^2}{9} <1, x^2+y^2 >1 \} $

And I want to integrate over some sort of function
$ \int_G f(x) dx $ .

I was researching the hole day about methods of determining the right boundarys for a double integral.

I would be very greatful, if someone can help me getting there !

Answer (score 0):

Given a function $g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\mapsto g(x,y)$, then
$$
\int_G g(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\int_{-y}^{y^2} g(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\left(\int_{-y}^{y^2} g(x,y)\,dx\right)dy
$$

Comment: oh wow..a little embarassing ^^ I thought of something else i guess...okay, the second one is screaming transformation with polarkoordinates :-)